# SDWebImage cache management

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm currently seeking a solution that allows us to discern between older and newer cached objects in SDWebImage, specifically images in this context. Is there a method or solution available that enables the identification of older cached objects for subsequent deletion?

Appreciate your insights and assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that supports it. However, it would be better if the backend site returned a new URL whenever the image changed.

```swift
imageView.sd_setImage(with: ..., 
                      placeholderImage: ..., 
                      options: .refreshCached) //<- Here
```

Comment: Does this remove the oldest image(s) and keeps newer image(s)

Comment: It will remove the old URL then download and cache again.

Comment: Does this do in every app launch, what I want is to have cache clear in a periodic way. for example, the cache which is one month old (just an example) that would be  cleared, however, the images which are still in one month period of time should be remained.

Comment: You can set the cache time, i.e., 1 day, 1 week, etc. However, I don't think it can be set for specific URLs, it will apply to all. It's using NSCache under the hood. By using `.refreshCached` option. You're saying that every single time `imageView` downloads a new image, it will not take from the cache.